# Scraping ASP Page with Python

Tags: python, asp.net

I'm trying to access an asp page to get data from a website but it always redirects my to its main page. I've tried setting allow_redirect to false but that throws an error, saying "the object has moved and can be found at href=main.htm". The website requires basic auth.

-The url I want the data from is:

```
example.com.au/blah/webpage.asp
```

However, whenever I run the requests.get command, it redirects to example.com.au/blah/main.htm.

my code:

```
url = "https://example.com.au/blah/webpage.asp"

s = requests.Session()

s.get(url, headers = {"Authorization" : auth})


r = requests.get(url, cookies = s.cookies, headers = {"Authorization" : auth})

print(r.url)
```

output:

```
example.com.au/blah/main.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the .asp page by first loading a primary asp page

```
s.get(example.com.au/blah/menu.asp)
```

then loading the asp page I wanted

```
r = s.get(example.com.au/blah/webpage.asp)
```

under the same session.